# How to know what means this 0 in this command of powerShell ? get-counter -Counter "\Process(0)\% Processor Time"

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage

I am totally beginner in power-shell, I read about you can write, for example:

```
get-counter -Counter "\Process(powershell)\% Processor Time"
```

But I received an error for that, I have to write, for example:

```
Get-Counter -counter "\\desktop-nrvk0ar\procesador(powershell)\% de tiempo de procesador"
Get-Counter : La ruta del contador de rendimiento \\desktop-nrvk0ar\procesador(powershell)\% de 
tiempo de procesador no es válida.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ Get-Counter -counter "\\desktop-nrvk0ar\procesador(powershell)\% de t ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterPathIsInvalid,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

I don't receive an error if I write the number like:

```
get-counter -Counter "\Process(1)\% Processor Time"
get-counter -Counter "\Process(_total)\% Processor Time"
```

How can I know what means this 0 or 1, or _total?
Thank so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters you provided represent the `InstanceName` of the counter you are trying to collect the information from.
The instances names may vary between the `Counters`.

Use `(Get-Counter -ListSet Process).PathsWithInstances` command to get information regarding the `Process` counter.
You could also use this command for any other counter. In order to see the complete list of counters, simply use `Get-Counter -ListSet *`

More [examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-5.1).

**Back to your question:**

Process counter is expecting the parameter to be a process name. That's the reason (0, 1. _total) are not working.

This sample would return process time for Notepad:

```
Get-counter -Counter "\Process(notepad)\% Processor Time"
```

**Edit:**
If you are attempting to run the command on a remote computer, please add the computer name as the parameter:

```
Get-counter -Counter "\Process(notepad)\% Processor Time" -ComputerName "computer_name"
```

Comment: But If write a name  I have an error, I don't have an error if I write the number like 0, 1 or _total

Comment: Could you please include the error output in your question? Also, the version of Powershell using $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.

Comment: Is desktop-nrvk0ar your computer or remote ?

Comment: It is my remote computer

Comment: I added to my answer.